# How to get System IP using Java?

Tags: java, network-programming

I was trying to make a jFrame which had a button & a text-area/label, the motive being able to retrieve my systems IP Address, the problem is, when I use this code

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try
        {
            InetAddress ownIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            jTextField1.setText(ownIP.getHostAddress());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            jTextField1.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But then this gives me back the loop back IP Address, 127.0.0.1 :(
I have static IP configured on my system, but then too that IP does not show up
I use NetBeans IDE 7.0 & Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Check this out, it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494465/how-to-enumerate-ip-addresses-of-all-enabled-nic-cards-from-java

Comment: None of 'em is working, wonder why... :(

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain all IP addresses for your system. Use the [NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces%28%29) method to retrieve all of the network interfaces. For each of the returned interfaces, use the [getInetAddresses()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getInetAddresses%28%29) method to retrieve all of the associated addresses.

Comment: You probably either want `wlan0` or `eth0`. `lo` refers to loopback.

Comment: You could filter out loopback by using the isLoopback() method.  If you run both IPv4 and IPv6, you might also want to filter one or the other out by checking the type of InetAddress against Inet4Address or Inet6Address.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` gives me my *real* ip address.

FYI, I ran it from a unit test within Eclipse on a macbook.

Comment: It still gives me 127.0.0.1 as my output :(