# Java program and ipconfig shows different IP address

Tags: java, ip, ipconfig

Recently the IP address of my system as show by the **ipconfig** has changed from 10.2.200.76 to 10.2.200.75
but the IP address returned by the following java code

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

is still 10.2.200.76.
My question is, "how is that possible?" I'm speculating that something is wrong with the either DHCP or Java.

---

**System Details -**
OS : Windows 7,
Java : Oracle JDK 7,
Ethernet Card : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit

**Update 1:**
Java Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("IP Address : " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output of java code> IP Address : 10.2.200.76

Ipconfig Output:
[Output of ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZPop.jpg)

Comment: You may have multiple IPs. Is 10.2.200.75 the only one returned by ipconfig ?

Comment: Yes 10.2.200.75 is the only IP returned by the ipconfig. I've got only two adapters, loopback and ethernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you enumerate all the IP addresses and see your old IP is still there in outout. Also try to restart the machine and check it again.Refer below.

[InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() is returning 127.0.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444753/inetaddress-getlocalhost-gethostaddress-is-returning-127-0-1-1)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getInetAddresses()

Comment: I've only two adapters loopback and ethernet adapter. Also I've tied restarting my system twice. The problem still exists.

Comment: Can you share the code and current ipconfig output?

Comment: Java Code > System.out.println("IP Address : " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()); Output > IP Address : 10.2.200.76 | Ipconfig output > Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : AD.AGI
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b8b5:481d:ee86:9e3e%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.200.75
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.203.254

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the **host** file located at **%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc** had an entry as follows

```
localhost 10.2.200.76
```

And I think java was picking this when I used

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

So, I changed the localhost entry to

```
localhost 127.0.0.1
```

Now both ipconfig and the above java api are returning the same IP address which 10.2.200.75.