# How can I get my computer's IP (Java/Selenium)?

Tags: java, selenium, ip

So far, I do the following:

```
driver.get("http://www.whatismyip.com/");
String myIP = driver.findElement(By.id("greenip")).getText();
System.out.println(myIP);
```

Is there any better way?

(PS: I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/how-to-get-ip-address-of-our-own-system-using-java) But NetworkInterface give multiple IPs and on the other hand `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` gives wrong IP. )

Comment: You may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083479/java-getting-my-ip-address Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/how-to-get-ip-address-of-our-own-system-using-java

Comment: What do you mean by better?  Faster, more reliable?  The best way wouldn't involve selenium at all

Comment: Thank you for reply. I use Selenium only because I do not know any other way. Is there any other way?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that you don't know anything about networking, and don't understand that your computer has a non-routable, private IP address.

Comment: The best way to get your external IP is to to *ask someone else*, as in the website you are using. Leave it as that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing is there is no such thing like my ip. Your machine can have multiple interfaces and each interface can have multiple IPs. so i dnt really think you want to get into it. All you can do is to try web APIs to get your external IP address. Here is a code in java which is actually just looking for your ip on internet with the help of these sites

```
    public static String getIpAddress() 
    { 
    URL myIP;
    try {
        myIP = new URL("http://api.externalip.net/ip/");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(myIP.openStream())
                );
        return in.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        try 
        {
            myIP = new URL("http://myip.dnsomatic.com/");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(myIP.openStream())
                    );
            return in.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e1) 
        {
            try {
                myIP = new URL("http://icanhazip.com/");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(myIP.openStream())
                        );
                return in.readLine();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }
    }

return null;
}
```

now with this you can get your ip from the internet but again that is your external IP