# Java: Socket programming - getting my System IP address using InetAddress

Tags: java, sockets

Using InetAddress, I'm always getting loopback address even if I am connected to network and the Ip obtained from dhcp is something like : 172.17.13.41. Why ?

I've something like this :

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
String myIp = address.getHostAddress();
System.out.println(myIp); // I expect the output 172.17.13.41 not 127.0.1.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same problem is solved in this question: [Java getting my IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083479/java-getting-my-ip-address)

Or how is your problem different?

Comment: Ya I got it. But I've few doubts:

Comment: I'm getting output as 'eth0 fe80:0:0:0:216:d3ff:feeb:eaf9%2' followed by 'eth0 172.17.13.41'        
   what is this first line in output? Is it a Inet-6 address? If so can we filter out Inet-4 and Inet-6 addresses ?

Comment: And what is the use of iface.isUp() method ?

Comment: Yes, fe80::/10 should be local addresses in IPv6. I suggest that you try checking the addresses by some regular expression (to distinguish between IPv4 and IPv6).

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("172.17.13.41");
String myIp = address.getHostAddress();
System.out.println(myIp); // I expect the output 172.17.13.41
```

As per java doc, `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` may return loop back address.

Comment: But Thats what I want to find. If I don't know that my IP is 172.17.13.41, how could I use getByName("172.17.13.41") method ?

Comment: You're kidding, right? If you know the answer you can get the answer? -1