# Java Getting IPv4 Address

Tags: java, ip-address, inetaddress

Regarding this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083479/java-getting-my-ip-address) where using the codes provided to produce the IP addresses.

```
String ip;
    try {
       Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
            // filters out 127.0.0.1 and inactive interfaces
            if (iface.isLoopback() || !iface.isUp())
                continue;

            Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
            while(addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
                ip = addr.getHostAddress();
                System.out.println(iface.getDisplayName() + " " + ip);
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I have implement the exact codes to get the IP addresses but it provides both the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Below is the value that was produced.

```
Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Network Adapter 192.168.1.5
Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Network Adapter fe80:0:0:0:a874:xxxx:xxxx:9150%wlan0
```

(IPv6 address redacted)

Is there any way that I could only get the IPv4 value and not both?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check the type of the `addr` object to see if it's an `Inet4Address` or an `Inet6Address` instance.

For example:

```
String ip;
try {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
        // filters out 127.0.0.1 and inactive interfaces
        if (iface.isLoopback() || !iface.isUp())
            continue;

        Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
        while(addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();

            // *EDIT*
            if (addr instanceof Inet6Address) continue;

            ip = addr.getHostAddress();
            System.out.println(iface.getDisplayName() + " " + ip);
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```