# Get own IP address in a java class invoked by a Session Bean

Tags: java, ip, jboss7.x

Suppose I have a statefull session bean B, which creates some POJO A. How can I inside one of the A's methods obtain the IP(and hostname) of the Java EE server which manages the session bean B?

PS. If this is not possible, then how could I do **the same in B** itself?

Comment: Duplicate of [another question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494465/how-to-enumerate-ip-addresses-of-all-enabled-nic-cards-from-java

Comment: No duplicate. They parse the results of ipconfig/use InetAddress. I'm talking about getting the info from a J2EE server container(-s) which run this application.

Comment: I don't think there is a generic API. But you could try to look at the JMX attributes exposed by your J2EE container.

Comment: Can it somehow be done using a dependency injection?

Comment: Sure, if you know the IP, you can inject it as a string attribute into your beans. :)

Answer (score 2):

In jboss 7 (as well as all the other jboss servers at least from 4.x on).

You have a property file that holds the bind ip.

I think in jboss 7.1 is called:

```
jboss.bind.address
```

And in theory can be accessed by using `System.getProperty`

Regards

PS: Needless to say, this is always local to the jvm, so no remote invocation unless you provide some sort of api for it, or the jboss folks already build a remote api for this.

Comment: When bound to 0.0.0.0 it will output exactly that value (i.e. if I run the server using ./standalone -b 0.0.0.0) + it is J2EE server specific.

Comment: I tend to bind to specific IPs in the box (that are also not the primary IP of the box) I do not like using port offsets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [java.net.InetAddress#getLocalHost](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) for this.

E.g.

```
InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
byte[] rawIP = host.getAddress();
String name = host.getHostName();
// etc
```

Comment: Nope, there might be several interfaces with several IPs on the machine. How should I know that a given IP is the one my J2EE server listens on?