# InetAddress getHostAddress() method gives different outputs when the laptop is connected to internet and not connected to internet?

Tags: java, ip, host, inetaddress

```
InetAddress address= InetAddress.getLocalHost();

System.out.println(address.getHostName()+ "------"+address.getHostAddress());
```

---

There are 2 types of Outputs for above codes at 2 different occations.

They are:

1) when internet is connected: 
`Samitha-Pc------10.224.108.58`
2) when internet is not connected):
`Samitha-Pc------127.0.0.1`

What is the reason for this difference? How the host has been changed from localhost to the ISP given ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is the internal ip (`localhost`). When you are connected to the router, it assigns you another ip address. `10.224.108.58` is the ip assigned by your router. See [http://www.howtogeek.com/126304/why-is-the-localhost-ip-127.0.0.1/](http://www.howtogeek.com/126304/why-is-the-localhost-ip-127.0.0.1/.). When you are not connected to the internet, the only available ip is localhost.

Comment: So when I am connected to internet there should be 2 localhost IP addresses as u say? So then I should be able to get both these IP addresses as localhost when connected to internet. Is that so.? If yes how to get that?

Comment: It chooses one of them. To get all of them see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494465/how-to-enumerate-ip-addresses-of-all-enabled-nic-cards-from-java

Answer (score 1):

When you are connected to internet your laptop has the IP Addr 10.224.108.58; when you are not connected to internet, no IP addres is associated to the laptop so the default one is used; the default one is 127.0.0.1